# Set git diff tool with DiffMerge on Mac

Tags: git

I have set up my git to use an external diff toll, DiffMerge.
After all, if I invoke git diff, DiffMerge is not called and it opens the default git diff tool.

These are my gitconfig:

```
diff.tool=diffmerge
difftool.diffmerge.cmd=/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/diffmerge $LOCAL $REMOTE  
merge.tool=diffmerge
mergetool.diffmerge.trustexitcode=true
mergetool.diffmerge.cmd=/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/diffmerge --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
mergetool.keepbackup=false
```

Comment: Check if you System or Global setting overrides this setting, check with ` git config --global merge.tool`

Comment: Are you sure that DiffMerge is installed in your global Applications directory and not in the [User Application Directory](https://www.engadget.com/2010/12/03/mac-101-the-two-applications-folders/)? (`~/Applications/...`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get DiffMerge set up as my default merge tool I used the instructions found here: https://coderwall.com/p/3wuuda/set-diffmerge-as-default-merge-tool-in-os-x

Pretty much, just run these commands:

```
git config --global merge.tool diffmerge

git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge --merge --result=\$MERGED \$LOCAL \$BASE \$REMOTE"

git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
```

If the diffmerge command is not found, try this:

```
ln -s /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/Resources/diffmerge.sh /usr/local/bin/diffmerge
```

After doing this, I was able to run `git mergetool` and DiffMerge opened and allowed me to resolve a file with conflicts and after saving and closing, it opened with the next file with conflicts.